# Set nested value in C# using Reflection

Tags: c#

I have a class named Article which uses another class named ZoneStock.
This ZoneStock class has an integer ID.

I want to modify it using reflection, but it doesn't work.

I found some examples on Stack Overflow, but I didn't manage to make it work.

```
public void Edit(int Id, string Key, string Value)
    {
        Article Article = Db.ArticleById(Id);
      if (Key.Contains("."))  // in this case, Key = ZoneStock.Id
        {
            string[] Keys = Key.Split('.');

            PropertyInfo Lvl1 = Article.GetType().GetProperty(Keys[0]); //Keys[0] = ZoneStock

            Type T = Lvl1.PropertyType;
            PropertyInfo Lvl2 = T.GetProperty(Keys[1]); //Keys[1] = Id


            // Before this point it works, after ....

            Lvl2.SetValue(Lvl1, Convert.ChangeType(Value, Lvl2.PropertyType), null);
            Db.Update(ref Article);
        }
        else
        {
            // .......
        }
        Db.Save();

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work" and "I didn't manage to make it work?"  Please explain what is not working.  Are you getting an error?  Is it crashing?  Is the Database not updating as you expect?  Did the code manage to inadvertently send a text message to the Pope?

Comment: @pstrjds Pretty sure the Pope would have closed it as off-topic for the Vatican.

Comment: Article Article seems bad.you should change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem, here it is:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public string Edit(int Id, string Key, string Value)
    {
        Article Article = Db.ArticleById(Id);

        if (Key.Contains(".")) //Property is a custom class
        {
            string[] Keys = Key.Split('.');

            PropertyInfo prop = Article.GetType().GetProperty(Keys[0]);
            Type type = prop.PropertyType;

            object propInstance = Db.Object(type, Convert.ToInt32(Value)); // See the code of this method below

            prop.SetValue(Article, propInstance);

            Db.Update(ref Article);
        }
        else // Property is a simple type: string, int, double, dattime etc.
        {
            PropertyInfo prop = Article.GetType().GetProperty(Key);
            prop.SetValue(Article, Convert.ChangeType(Value, prop.PropertyType), null);
            Db.Update(ref Article);
        }
        Db.Save();

        return Value;
    }

 public static object Object(Type type, int Id)
    {
        object Obj = Ctx.Set(type).Find(Id); //Ctx is may entityFramework Context
        return Obj;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're getting an error message like "Object does not match target type" because you're assigning the value from the parameter to a type directly (Lvl1) instead of the instance of the type. Something like the code below should do the direct assignment.

```
var newValue = Convert.ChangeType(Value, Lvl2.PropertyType);
Lvl2.SetValue(Lvl1.GetValue(Article), newValue);
```

Update based new requirement from comment

If the level 1 property may be null, the code below will instantiate an instance of the property type.

```
// Article.ZoneStack is null
if (Lvl1.GetValue(Article) == null)
    Lvl1.SetValue(Article, Activator.CreateInstance(Lvl1.PropertyType));
// Article.ZoneStack now has a new instance of ZoneStack assigned
var newValue = Convert.ChangeType(Value, Lvl2.PropertyType);
Lvl2.SetValue(Lvl1.GetValue(Article), newValue);
// Article.ZoneStack.Id == newValue
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Yes, you're right.

Unfortunately, Lvl1 instance doen't exist because it's the first time I asign a value to it.
Lvl1.GetValue(Article) returns null
and your solution returns 
"A non static method require a target"

Comment: The wording on your question made it seem the ZoneStack already existed for the article (also since you were doing a Db.Update). If you're assigning a new ZoneStack, hopefully your Db.Update handles the insert/update if it doesn't already exist. I updated the answer to include instantiating the level 1 property.

Comment: Thank you.

After some tests yesterday I found this solution with activator.

It works Pretty well but I still have a problem.

I will describe it later.

Thanks